# AJAX en DATATABLE no envía parámetros

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, datatables

Quiero crear una DATATABLE con dos variables (es un filtro de fechas para obtener los registros en ese rango) que se enviarán por POST desde un AJAX pero me retorna el siguiente error:

> DataTables warning: table id=tb_control_nomina_maestros - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1.

En mi código JS valido campos vacíos y un rango de fecha correcto; al cumplir con esto busco crear la DATATABLE pasándole estas dos variables por POST en AJAX y me retorne el JSON para llenar la tabla.

Código JS:

```javascript
function control_nomina_maestros() {
$('#btn_filtrar').click(function () {
    
    //Obtener fechas para filtrar
    var initial_date = $('#txt_fecha1').val();
    var end_date = $('#txt_fecha2').val();

    //Validación de campos vacíos o rango de fechas incorrecto incorrecto
    if (
    initial_date.length == 0 ||
    end_date.length == 0 ||
    initial_date > end_date
    ) {

    alertify.error('Selecciona un Rango de Fecha Válido');
    alertify.alert().close();

    } else {

    //Listar en DataTable
    $("#tb_control_nomina_maestros").DataTable({
    language: {
    "decimal": "",
    "emptyTable": "No Hay Información.",
    "info": "Mostrando _END_ registros de un total de _TOTAL_.",
    "infoEmpty": "No Hay Registros.",
    "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de un Total de _MAX_ Registros)",
    "infoPostFix": "",
    "thousands": ",",
    "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ Registros.",
    "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
    "processing": "Procesando...",
    "search": "Buscar:  ",
    "zeroRecords": "Sin Resultados Encontrados.",
    "paginate": {
        "first": "Primero",
        "last": "Ultimo",
        "next": "Siguiente",
        "previous": "Anterior"
    }
    },

    "ajax": {
    "url": "webServices/nomina_maestros/control.php",
    "type": "POST",
    "data": {
        "d1": initial_date,
        "d2": end_date
          }
    },

    "columns": [
    { "data": "id_payroll" },
    { "data": "name" },
    { "data": "concept" },
    { "data": "total" },
    { "data": "apply_date" }

    ]

});
    }

});
}
```

En el código PHP preparo la consulta y ejecuto con los dos parámetros obtenidos por POST desde la DATATABLE.

Código PHP:

```php
<?php
    
require_once('../../config/conexion.php');

$stmt = $db_con->prepare(
    "SELECT
    id_payroll,
    (SELECT concat_WS(' ', name, last_name) FROM tb_teacher WHERE tb_payroll_teacher.id_teacher = tb_teacher.id_teacher) as name,
    concept,
    total,
    apply_date
    FROM tb_payroll_teacher
    WHERE apply_date BETWEEN :d1 AND :d2"
);
$stmt->bindParam(':d1', $_POST['d1'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':d2', $_POST['d2'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute(array());

while ($data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $array["data"][] = $data;
}

echo json_encode($array);

$db_con = null;
```

Comment: hazle un echo a $array en el momento que le asignas datos para saber como lo está llenando por que tengo la impresión que no se está llenando correctamente

Comment: Hola @Osaskoh, ya lo he solucionado (Comparto solución en la respuesta) el array retornaba el JSON correctamente pero debía ejecutarse así sin más; no era necesidad determinarlo como arreglo ¡Gracias!.

Answer (score 0):

Lo he solucionado; al pasarse parámetros en "BindParam", ya no era necesario determinarlo como arreglo al momento de ejecutar el `$stmt` en el archivo PHP.

Código JS correcto:

```
//Listado de nomina_maestros en DataTable
    $("#tb_control_nomina_maestros").DataTable({
    language: {
        "decimal": "",
        "emptyTable": "No Hay Información.",
        "info": "Mostrando _END_ registros de un total de _TOTAL_.",
        "infoEmpty": "No Hay Registros.",
        "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de un Total de _MAX_ Registros)",
        "infoPostFix": "",
        "thousands": ",",
        "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ Registros.",
        "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
        "processing": "Procesando...",
        "search": "Buscar:  ",
        "zeroRecords": "Sin Resultados Encontrados.",
        "paginate": {
            "first": "Primero",
            "last": "Ultimo",
            "next": "Siguiente",
            "previous": "Anterior"
        }
    },

    "ajax": {
        "url": "webServices/nomina_maestros/control.php",
        "type": "POST",
        "data": {
                 d1 : initial_date,
                 d2: end_date
                },
    },

    "columns": [
        { "data": "id_payroll" },
        { "data": "name" },
        { "data": "concept" },
        { "data": "total" },
        { "data": "apply_date" },

    ]

});
```

Código PHP correcto:

```
    <?php

require_once('../../config/conexion.php');

//$_POST['d1'] = "2022-07-01";
//$_POST['d2'] = "2022-07-15";

$stmt = $db_con->prepare(
    "SELECT
    id_payroll,
    (SELECT concat_WS(' ', name, last_name) FROM tb_teacher WHERE tb_payroll_teacher.id_teacher = tb_teacher.id_teacher) as name,
    concept,
    total,
    apply_date
    FROM tb_payroll_teacher
    WHERE apply_date BETWEEN CAST(:date1 as DATE) AND CAST(:date2 as DATE)"
);
$stmt->bindParam(':date1', $_POST['d1']);
$stmt->bindParam(':date2', $_POST['d2']);
$stmt->execute();

while ($data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $array["data"][] = $data;
}

echo json_encode($array);

$db_con = null;
```